# show input value in error message using jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I just want to include value entered by the user in text field. I am using `"{0}"` key but it is returning true and false. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61pptcb3/4/)

```
 $.validator.addMethod("specialChar", function(value, element){     
    var patt = new RegExp(/[^A-z]/g);
  return !patt.test(value)
 },"{0} is not valid");

    $('#myform').validate({
        onfocusout:function(element){           
            this.element(element)
        },
        rules:{
            username:{
                required:true,
                specialChar:true
            }
        },

        messages:{
            "username": {
                required: "Please enter user name"


            }


        }
    })
```

Comment: In patt.test(value) - test method will return boolean only. So you are appending boolean to your return message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign the value to this.value and then instead of string message use function that returns string. Inside that function you have access to this.value

Have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xq128ky/)

```
$.validator.addMethod("specialChar", function(value, element){ 
  this.val = value;
  return false;
}, function() {
  return 'not allowed ' + this.val;
});
```