# set dynamic message from javascript validation rules like $(element).rules("add",

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, customization

I need to set dynamic validation message for a custom date range validator for input from datepicker.

I have created a validator method like -

```
$.validator.addMethod("minMaxDatevalidation", function (value, element) { 
...})
```

And created a custom rule like -

```
$(element).rules("add", {
    minMaxDatevalidation: true,
    messages: { minMaxDatevalidation: "The " + fieldDisplayName + " field 
    must be on or after the " + moment(pastDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY") + "."
    }
});
```

But this validation messages in the above add rules section - this I want dynamic - for date selected than a particular year then above or if selected date is more than a particular year than future error message.

I tried to return custom message from validator addMethod, but it's not working.

Any help regarding setting dynamic message in the rules section would be great.

Using Jquery datepicker.

Comment: What error do you get? And which validation plugin are you using?

Comment: I just need to display a dynamic message. I'm using jquery.

Comment: `$.validator.addMethod` methods are not jQuery's, these are usually provided by validator plugins. Please check your page's source code to see if there is any other validation library included other than jQuery.

Comment: Yes it is, jquery validation plugin only. We're also using foolproof, but extending jquery for validations.

Comment: You can define the custom message when you are creating the new rule using `addMethod`. This method takes a third parameter, which can be a function returning the message string. Check this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352626/dynamic-jquery-validate-error-messages-with-addmethod-based-on-the-element#answer-13352987

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show input value in error message using jquery validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491260/show-input-value-in-error-message-using-jquery-validation)

Comment: Custom message is fine, but how to use dynamic. I'm able to pass custom by almost 2 methods, but how to set the message dynamic

Comment: you get the value of current field in that third function of `addMethod`. You can use that field's value when you return your message string e.g. `return "You entered " + element.value + ", which is not correct.";` You can also define another date variable inside the same function that you want to use for comparison. Hope it makes sense?

Comment: I get that, but that's something custom. I want dynamic, at runtime and not always showing same message.

Comment: You want the error message like this - `"The " + fieldDisplayName + " field 
    must be on or after the " + moment(pastDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY") + "."` ? Or you want message to sometimes be like this and some other times something else?